# Doing animation with ng-show without ngAnimate

Tags: css, angularjs, carousel, css-animations, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to do a wipe-in animation for my ng-show. Basically, I want to achieve this simple animation as shown in [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/knSlxwA3tVGsBV2tRnly?p=preview) here.

I know that ngShow has a hook for ng-animate since angular 1.3. However, the situation is a bit complicated. I have a carousel that I extend using angular UI Carousel bootstrap. The bootstrap has a bug with Chrome, so ngAnimate needs to be disabled for all elements under the `carousel` tag. I need animation for element under my carousel, but if I include ngAnimate, my carousel won't work in Chrome -- as described in their github issue tracker [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1565)

As a workaround, I am thinking to do the animation using traditional CSS bootstrap to my ng-show inside my carousel. I did some research but I have no luck so far. Is this possible? And does anybody try this before? Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you tried doing the animation by hand using the `$animate` service?

Comment: @getOffMyLawn sorry, im pretty new to angularJs, but from what I understand $animate service is part of ngAnimate? and all animation is disabled for components under carousel :(

Comment: I'm sorry, I confused things, yes $animate is part of ngAnimate and all animations are done using this service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ng-class` directive instead of `ng-show` and `ng-hide` which will conditionally add class to the element that should wipe-in, invoking the desired transition, giving basically the same effect and omitting entirely the `ngAnimate` module.
Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vfrmmuGjsIfsdhnLj87O?p=preview) showing the implementation.