# Angular: Fade in/out without including module NgAnimate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, ng-animate

I'm building a small web app in Angular that includes a form with a "save changes" button.

I'd like to show a green tick signifying a correct update of the data, with a quick fade-in/fade-out animation.

I don't think it's worth adding a 20-ish Kb module just for that animation (I don't need to animate any other part of the app).

Is there an alternative way to perform a simple animation such as this without including NgAnimate, that preferably keeps in line with the "Angular way"?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/vfrmmuGjsIfsdhnLj87O?p=preview ?  Which came from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323044/doing-animation-with-ng-show-without-nganimate

Comment: but... that code includes angular-animate.js? If I remove the script the code doesn't work.

Comment: Doh i missed that, the answer stated it had omitted ng-animate

Comment: do you think into install a npm package for animations? https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/

Comment: mmm... Maybe if I can extract the relevant animations from the css... I'll give it a try, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way - you can make use of CSS animations, `$timeout` and `ng-class`. Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/9ps7gr2e/2/).

Basically you toggle the flag in parent controller

```
ctrl.showCheckmark = function() {
    ctrl.isShowingCheckmark = true;

    $timeout(function() {
        ctrl.isShowingCheckmark = false;
    }, 2000);
}
```

and watch the changes in checkmark component.

When the flag changes you set visibility and fade-in flags:

```
$ctrl.show = function() {
    $ctrl.isShowing = true;

    $timeout(function() {
        $ctrl.fadeIn = true;
        $ctrl.fadeOut = false;
    });
};
```

using `$timeout` to wait for previous `$digest` to finish and render `ng-if="$ctrl.isShowing"`.

All that's left is writing some CSS animations and it is super easy.

Comment: I ended up using a variant of your answer, but it boils down to using the timeout feature, classes and css. Thank you!